# AndroidのWebViewでリンクタップ時の読み込み先を変えたい

Tags: android, android-webview

webViewでタップされたUriを変化させて読み込みたいです。
具体的には、リンクのUriからJavaScriptの引数部分を取り除いたものをloadさせたいです。
例えば、

```
    <a href="http://example.com/index.html?id=hoge">
```

というhtmlの場合、index.html?id=hogeではなく、index.htmlを読み込ませたいです。どのようにすれば実現できるのでしょうか。

Answer (score -1):

JavascriptでURLの引数を取り除いては: `link.split('?')` はいちばんの`?`から引数を取り除きます：

```html
<body>
    <a href="http://example.com/index.html?id=hoge">link to example.com</a>
</body>
<script>
var link = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href;
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href = link.split('?')[0];
</script>
```